# Exportar datos desde un progama en cobol

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, txt, exportar, cobol

Necesito ayuda con lo siguiente: Tengo un programa hecho en Cobol hace unos 30 años y necesito extraer la base de datos. Por mi parte no tengo ningún conocimiento en absoluto de Cobol, estuve googleando un poco pero no conseguí nada que me solucione mi problema.

Leí que utilizaban rmcobol.exe y logré encontrarlo pero no logro entender como usarlo (cuando lo ejecuto abre un cmd y lo cierra automáticamente), también leí que con un programa "recover1" el cual no pude conseguir, sin embargo entre los archivos del rmcobol que descargué hay un "recover1" pero me sucede lo mismo que con rmcobol...

El resto de lo que pude encontrar es ya para quienes tienen algún conocimiento mas avanzado de Cobol...

Del programa tengo absolutamente todos los archivos a mi disposición.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Si tienes el código fuente (archivos .cbl), sería posible exportar los datos haciendo un programa que lea los registros y los guarde en un fichero de texto por ejemplo, puesto que tendríamos el tipo de archivo ```INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION/FILE-CONTROL``` y las descripciones de los registros ```FILE SECTION```. El programa recover1 era para recuperar los indices de un archivo indexado cuando este estaba corrupto. No hay ninguna utilidad para exportar un fichero a lo bruto, a no ser que sea un archivo sequencial, pero si es relativo o indexado tienes que hacer el programa que lo convierta.

Comment: Además es importante que la versión del compilador que utilices sea la misma con la que se hizo el programa, porque ahora mismo no la recuerdo exactamente, pero a partir de cierta versión, los archivos indexados cambiaban de tener el indice en el mismo archivo que los datos, a tenerlo en un fichero separado. Y los relativos cambiaba la estructura interna. La versión la puedes averiguar ejecutando el programa "runcobol.exe" de la aplicación que quieres recuperar, a veces le cambiaban el nombre por "run.exe" o "r.exe".

Comment: rmcobol.exe se ejecuta en entorno DOS o lo que actualmente llamamos el CMD o linea de comandos, si quieres ver por que se cierra o el mensaje que arroja debes abrir una consola de linea de comandos y ejecutarla desde ahí, y como dice el colega si tienes los archivos fuentes del programa tienes la mitad del trabajo hecho ya que bastaría con analizar el programa y ver lo que hace.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, apenas vuelva a casa ejecuto el peograma y reviso si dice la versión... Los archivos fuente estoy casi seguro que tengo todo... El tema es que al no conocer Cobol no tengo certeza... En cuanto al programa que menciona @DigiSoul, para poder hacer algo así tendría que tener una buena base de conocimiento sobre el funcionamiento de cobol imagino...

Comment: Ahí abrí el run.com y dice: RM/COBOL RUNTIME <Ver 2.1A > for DOS 2.n...

Comment: y efectivamente, tengo varios archivos .CBL, .COB, .SQZ, .INX, y varios sin extensión que asumo que seria de donde hay que extraer los datos porque al abrirlos con el editor de texto se puede ver que están la información pero imposible extraerla así debido a la codificación (hace unos meses pude entender el patrón de uno de los archivos e intenté aislar dato por dato manualmente pero me volví loco)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

al fin logré extraer los datos... Dejo acá los pasos para que quede registro por si alguien lo necesita...

En primer lugar, al ser archivos de una versión vieja de RM/Cobol (v2.1) tuve que actualizarlos a la nueva versión:

1. Descargar una versión mas actual del programa (Yo descargué la v5.36 de [aquí](https://vetusware.com/download/RMCOBOL-85%20Compiler%205.36/?id=12838)) (Es de 32 bit porque yo lo hice todo desde una máquina virtual).
2. Abrir la consola de windows
3. Colocarse en la ruta donde se encuentra el RM/Cobol y ejecutar `runcobol rmifca`
4. Colocar la ruta y nombre del archivo .INX
5. Colocar la ruta y nombre del archivo que contiene los datos (en mi caso sólo doy enter porque se llaman de la misma forma que el .INX pero sin extensión)
6. Dar enter cuando pregunta BLOCK CONTAINS (los deja en 0)
7. Dar enter cuando pregunta RECORD CONTAINS (lo deja en predet.)
   [image: rmifca]
8. Colocar ruta y nombre para el nuevo archivo actualizado (Asegurarse que sea una ruta existente)
9. Luego compilar el rmifcb ejecutando `rmcobol rmifcb.cbl`
10. Una vez compilado ejecutarlo (`runcobol rmifcb`) y cuando lo solicite escribir `y` y luego enter
11. El programa comenzará a trabajar, el proceso puede demorar algunos minutos dependiendo el tamaño del archivo. Presionar enter cuando finalice

- [Acá les dejo un link al instructivo en inglés que incluye otras versiones](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/9316915/rm-cobol-to-rm-cobol-85-conversion-guide-micro-focus).

Luego, una vez actualizado el archivo hay que utilizar una herramienta diseñada por JCantero llamada Mira (La pueden descargar de [acá](https://www.cobolforo.es/showpost.php?p=5129&postcount=8)).

1. Abrir la consola de windows
2. Colocarse en la ruta donde se encuentra Mira y ejecutar

`mira ruta_y_nombre_archivo_actualizado`

4. Una vez ejecutado, se inicia el proceso y al finalizar (nuevamente, demora depende el tamaño del archivo) se abre un archivo llamado "A" en un block de notas (ese archivo se encuentra en la carpeta de Mira)

Una vez realizado todo este proceso se debe importar al Excel. Yo lo hice con la versión 2013, dependiendo la versión puede diferir:

1. Ir a la pestaña "DATOS", y luego en el apartado "Obtener datos externos" seleccionar "Desde texto".
2. Seleccionar la opción "De ancho fijo" y las demás opciones según lo que necesite en cada situación y darle a "Siguiente"
3. Seleccionar donde se delimitará cada columna (un click agrega, dos clicks borra y para mover se debe arrastrar), luego darle a "Siguiente"
   [image: excel]
4. Establecer el formato deseado de cada columna y darle a "Finalizar"
5. Seleccionar desde donde se ubicarán los datos dentro de la hoja

Espero que le sirva a alguien porque a mi me hizo renegar bastante todo esto...

Saludos

Comment: Muchas, muchas gracias por compartir todo esto. Es una respuesta maravillosa.

Comment: Hola, recién intenté y me permitió descargar... De todas formas te lo subí a mega para que no tengas problemas... Saludos... Link a mega: https://mega.nz/file/Qsk0GRBJ#BJ6K1ZaxWB5wLCp4M56MitW8XbGrgfXyoIdWQn1l1ok

Comment: bien gracias manu